# Inserting array of Ids in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm trying to insert two rows but the id of every row is in the same array, how can I insert correctly?

Because I tried by this way but only insert me the first id.

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO cars(car, price, createdDate, createdBy) 
    VALUES (".$this->db->escape($ids).",
            ".$this->db->escape($price).",
            NOW(),
            ".$this->session->userdata('admin_id').")";             

    mysql_query($sql);
    echo ($sql);
```

This is what I get:

```
INSERT INTO cars (car, price, createdDate, createdBy) 
VALUES ('217450,217449', '15', NOW(), 150)
```

In car I want to insert the price, createdDate and createdBy on the two car Ids 217450,217449.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 'ids' are 'csv' values ?

Comment: Yes they are comma separated values.

Comment: use `explode` function to make it as separate array and insert....

Comment: @Torrezzzz yes I tried with explode but throw me error.

Comment: @devtreat: what error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ids = "217450, 217449";
$id_explode = explode(",", $ids);

foreach($id_explode as $id)
{
    $sql = "
             INSERT INTO cars(car, price, createdDate, createdBy) 
             VALUES (".$this->db->escape($id).",
             ".$this->db->escape($price).",
             NOW(),
             ".$this->session->userdata('admin_id').")
           ";             

   mysql_query($sql);
   echo ($sql);
}
```

But I recommend you not to use **raw SQL queries** as it is **vulnerable to SQL injection**.
Hence, Use CI's **`active record`**:

```
$ids = "217450, 217449";
$id_explode = explode(",", $ids);

$insert_batch = array();
foreach($id_explode as $id)
{
    $arr = array(
              'car' => $id,
              'price' => $price,
              'createdDate' => NOW(),
              'createdBy' => $this->session->userdata('admin_id'),
             );
    $insert_batch[] = $arr;
}

$this->db->insert_batch('cars', $insert_batch);
```

**Documentation:**

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: Happy to help. Also recommended a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP function `explode`:

```
$ids= explode(',', $ids);
foreach($ids as $id)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cars(car, price, createdDate, createdBy) 
        VALUES (" . $this->db->escape($id) . ", " . $this->db->escape($price)
        . ", NOW(), " . $this->session->userdata('admin_id') . ")";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use ids as array like
    $ids = array('217450','217449');

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO cars(car, price, createdDate, createdBy) 
VALUES ";
foreach($ids as $id){

$sql .=(".$this->db->escape($id).",
        ".$this->db->escape($price).",
        NOW(),
        ".$this->session->userdata('admin_id')."),";             
}
mysql_query($sql);
echo ($sql);
```

Now it will create query

```
 INSERT INTO cars (car, price, createdDate, createdBy)
VALUES ('217450', '15', NOW(), 150),('217450', '15', NOW(), 150);
```